# InvalidOperationException while saving an image to the media library

Tags: windows-phone-7, isolatedstorage

I'm trying to save an image to the media library, but I'm getting an "InvalidOperationException" when the SavePicture function is being called. I have an image file saved in the isolatedstorage that i want to save to the Pictures Hub. Here's the code snippet -

```
using (IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
    {
        using (IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = myIsolatedStorage.OpenFile(fname, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)) //fname is the filename of the image that is to be saved in the library
        {
            MediaLibrary mediaLibrary = new MediaLibrary();
            Picture pic = mediaLibrary.SavePicture("SavedLogo.jpg", fileStream); //Exception thrown here!
            fileStream.Close(); 
        }
    }
```

From what i've gathered, this exception has something to do with Zune blocking out the Images library when it is running. I have it stopped and don't have a phone connected to the PC either.
When i test this app on a physical device, the app just crashes, although i can see a blank image saved in the "Saved Pictures".

I'm downloading the image from a url using a webclient and it seems correct. The webclient is passed the image's url (openReadAsync). Here's the openReadCompleted event :

```
void client_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            var resInfo = new StreamResourceInfo(e.Result, null);
            var reader = new StreamReader(resInfo.Stream);

            byte[] contents;
            using (BinaryReader bReader = new BinaryReader(reader.BaseStream))
            {
                contents = bReader.ReadBytes((int)reader.BaseStream.Length);
            }
            IsolatedStorageFile isf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
            IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = isf.CreateFile("example.jpg");
            stream.Write(contents, 0, contents.Length);
            stream.Close();
         }
```

I think it is saving the file correctly (in the isolatedsotrage, that is) because it is displaying it successfully when i try and open it later.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the image saved correctly? MSDN has a great resources for saving pictures to the MediaLibrary
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769549(v=vs.92)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769549%28v=vs.92%29)

Comment: I haven't used the exact method on there. I've added what I've done to save the image.